# Need of a specific trick to manage bash eval cmd & <<< input

Tags: bash, scrapy

I want to use several instances of a spider object of scrapy with several instances of polipo proxies.

For this, it is quite simple:

```
for i in `seq 1 100`
    do
        numeroPortProxy=$(($i+30000))
        command="scrapy crawl courses_PT ... -s HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:${numeroPortProxy}"
        eval $command&
    done
```

My issue is I need to answer automatically `"o"` to the command.

I tried this `eval $command&<<<"o"`, it does not work. The logfile indicates: `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

I tried this too `eval $command<<<"o" &`, it does not work too. It gives this error in the terminal:

```
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

crawl: error: Invalid -s value, use -s NAME=VALUE
```

Well it does not appreciate.

So, how can I do to launch several instances of command at one time like `&` operator allows and to answer the prompt of each several instances like `<<<` allows.

Comment: What is the point of **eval** here?

Comment: Did you try `echo "o" | scrapy ...`? Good luck.

Comment: I'd remove the `command` variable and `eval`, and just execute the command directly (`scrapy crawl ... ${numeroPortProxy} <<<"o" &`). The variable and `eval` thing might not be the problem, but it's useless and has the opportunity for weird bugs. Try running `command="echo '6 * 9'"; eval $command` for a simple example of the sort of thing that can happen.

Comment: @shellter thank you, that way it works perfectly `echo "o" | (scrapy crawl ... -s HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:${numeroPortProxy}) &`.

Comment: @oguzismail the point was I putted it in a string. I could put it between parentheses `(scapy crawl ...)&<<<"o" ` but I am not sure it would change the issue.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I follow a part of your advice with the parentheses. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: @AvyWam : Glad that helped. As no one has posted a full answer, you can post an answer to your own Q and then accept it after 48? hrs to gain valuable reputation points. Good luck to all!

Comment: @AvyWam Actually, I didn't mean to imply you should use parentheses (they were part of my comment, like these). In this shell context, parentheses create a subshell, which isn't needed or relevant; try it without them.